# Detecting input redirection file

Tags: java

How can we detect/fetch the name of a file that's fed as an input redirection to a java program from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Without OS-specific hacks (such as running `ps -ef`) you can't.

Why do you need this information, and why can't you restructure your program to simply take the file as a command-line argument?

Comment: The info's needed because I need to update the information in the file - by creating a temp file with the updated info, deleting the old file and renaming the temp file. That's why I needed the name of the file. your suggestion is a good work around though. thanks!